# Netlify "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" Even though the origin is set on my express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, netlify

I am hosting my React app on netlify and am having a CORS issue where even though I have my origin defined on my express API for the desired route I am still getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://e46finder.herokuapp.com/auth' from origin 'https://warm-trifle-0ebd9b.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What makes even less sense to me is that when I make a request to my API from another route on my frontend, let's take my '/scrape' endpoint for example It returns to my frontend with no errors and the request is being sent from the same origin for both request 'https://warm-trifle-0ebd9b.netlify.app'.

I did some digging and found this post https://answers.netlify.com/t/access-control-allow-origin-policy/1813/2 saying that he basically had the same issue as me and was able to fix it by adding '[headers.values] Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *' in his netlify.toml file so I also tired that but it still did not fix my issue.

**My API express code:**

```
        const cors = require("cors");
        
            const corsOptions ={
               origin: ['https://warm-trifle-0ebd9b.netlify.app', 'https://warm-trifle-0ebd9b.netlify.app/'], 
               credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
               preflightContinue: true,
               optionSuccessStatus:200,
            }
            
            app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    
    async function getcookie(req) {
        res.send()
    
        var authCookie = await req.cookies.AccessToken;
        accessToken = globalToken;
        if (authCookie = await req.cookies.AccessToken) {
            try {
                if (authCookie === req.headers.cookie) {
                    authCookie = authCookie
                        .split('; ')
                        .find(row => row.startsWith('AccessToken='))
                        .split('=')[1];
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            finally {
                if (authCookie == accessToken) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
    
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    };
    
    
    app.get('/auth', async (req, res) => {
        var authornot = await getcookie(req);
    
        if (authornot === true) {
            if (keepUserLoggedIn == true) {
                res.cookie("LoggedIn", true, {
                    sameSite: 'None',
                    path: '/',
                    httpOnly: false,
                    maxAge: 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365 * 10,
                    secure: true
                });
            } else {
                res.cookie("LoggedIn", true, {
                    sameSite: 'None',
                    path: '/',
                    httpOnly: false,
                    secure: true
                });
          

  };
        res.status(200).json(true);
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(authornot);
        res.status(401).json(false);
    }
    res.send();
});

app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {      
    scraper(res, counter);
});
```

**My netlify.toml file**

```
# The following redirect is intended for use with most SPAs that handle
# routing internally.
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200

[[headers]]
  # Define which paths this specific [[headers]] block will cover.
  for = "/*"
    [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *
```